# Salesforce Flow: Which performs better? Assigning variables in Get element or in Default Value?

Tags: salesforce-lightning

Our company has been refactoring flows lately due to Apex timeouts, and we're trying to decide which method runs more efficiently.

Previously, we would get a Get element to assign values of a parent record to variables; however, it appears we can also create variables on their own and then define the value of a parent record's fields as the Default Value.

Ex. {!$Record.Parent_Record__r.Value}

My question is, on the backend, is it performing a DML for each of those variables if I set the value using the example above? Which method is more efficient, and which is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ***My question is, on the backend, is it performing a DML for each of those variables if I set the value using the example above?***

For my test, I did the following setup. I don't know if it matches your situation but thought it would work.

Project__c

--- Project_Item__c (Child object connected via master-detail)

Both objects have Dummy__c (Text: 255) field. I wrote my use-case to copy down the field value from the parent on upsert.

I think wrote two record trigger flows. BEFORE context (Fast Field Updates)

Scenario 1:

- Perform Get

Scenario 2:

- Use relationship field

I opened up the developer console. Set my debug level to Finest. I performed an update call on the child object with each scenario while the other flow was deactivated.

Findings:

Scenario 1:

- 1 DML
- 62 CPU time

[image]

[image]

Scanerio 2:

- 0 DML
- 3 CPU time

[image]

[image]

[image]

> > ***Which method is more efficient, and which is best practice?***

That is a little subjective here to personal taste. I prefer my flows to have the fewest nodes possible but still be easy to read. In this case, if efficiency is more the best practice, definitely go the assignment via lookup route. I generally do it that way anyways without thinking about it. Its usually easier too.

Comment: Thank you so much, that definitely answers the question.

As a follow-up, how did you get the log that shows the DML and CPU time?

Comment: Ryan, usually there is a YouTube video on how to do it via developer console. Something like "Salesforce developer console debugging". Or you can follow this. Just setting debugs to finest on all categories and running the logic as the tracked user. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5